# Add SVM with Convunational Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, keras, svm, activation, loss

I want to extract the feature with CNN, then classify with SVM. Therefore, I build a model and use "hinge " loss.

#### This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 128, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(filters,kernel_size,padding='valid',activation='relu',strides=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size))
model.add(Dense(38, W_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss='hinge',optimizer='adadelta')
```

However, I got this error.

#### error:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_1 to have
> the shape (None, 38) but got an array with shape (129083, 1)

I hope somebody can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `categorical_hinge` as you have 38 classes? Shouldn't you transform your target (`y`) to have a `one_hot_encoding` (you can use `OneHotEncoder` from `scikit learn`)?

Comment: from `model.add(Dense(38, W_regularizer=l2(0.01)))` we can assume you have 38 classes. So, @MarcinMożejko is correct. use categorical_hinge

Answer (score 0):

use `hinge_loss` as loss function

```
model.compile(loss='hinge_loss',optimizer='adadelta')
```